# Using num2str with matrices in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

Having issue with the `num2str` function in Octave.

**My code**:

```
>> alpha = zeros(1,length(alpha));
>> legendInfo = zeros(1,length(alpha));
>> legendInfo(1) = num2str(alpha(1));
```

**Error Message**:

> error: A(I) = X: X must have the same size as I

I've been trying to follow this link to no avail: [Link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/29799-adding-a-legend-and-different-coloured-lines-in-a-for-loop)

**Update:**

Based on suggestion, I have implemented the following code and have received the following error message:

```
>> labelInfo = cell(1,numel(alpha))
>> labelInfo{1} = num2str(alpha{1});
```

> error: matrix cannot be indexed with {
>
> error: evaluating argument list element number 1

**ANSWER**

The answer provided was accurate with one tweak:

- `alpha{1}` (Incorrect syntax)
- `alpha(1)` (Correct Syntax)

Parantheses rather than curly braces.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have initialized `legendInfo` to be a *numeric array* the same size as `alpha`. When you convert `alpha(1)` to a string, it is possibly more than 1 character long (i.e. `alpha(1) > 9`) which is obviously not going to fit into a single element in an array.

```
length(num2str(10))
%   2

length(legendInfo(1))
%   1
```

Also, even if `num2str(alpha(1))` yields a string that has a length of 1, it will implicitly convert it to a number (it's ASCII representation) which is likely not what you want.

```
legendInfo = zeros(1, numel(alpha));
legendInfo(1) = num2str(1);
%  49    0    0
```

Rather than a numeric array, you likely want a *cell array* to hold the legend info since you will have strings of varying lengths.

```
legendInfo = cell(1, numel(alpha));
legendInfo{1} = num2str(alpha{1});
```

If you look closely at the post you have linked, you'll see that they use the curly brackets `{}` to perform assignment rather than parentheses `()` indicating that they are creating a cell array.